# Teleril RadGridView Multiple GroupDescriptors Problem

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik

When I try to have two GroupDescriptors in the Telerik RadGridView which One has a Sum AggregateFunctions It overwrite the inner GroupDescriptor with the Caption given to the outer Group.

```
<telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
                                            <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="State">
                                                <telerik:GroupDescriptor.AggregateFunctions>
                                                    <telerik:SumFunction SourceField="NewCustomers" Caption="Total Customers:"/>
                                                </telerik:GroupDescriptor.AggregateFunctions>                                                    
                                            </telerik:GroupDescriptor>
                                            <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="RepWithCount" >                                                    
                                            </telerik:GroupDescriptor>
                                        </telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
```

Could anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.